# Using tbl.Filter to filter between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

This question relates to the Schematiq add-in for Microsoft Excel.

I can use =tbl.Filter(*table*, "Date", ">" & *date*) to filter on one date but could you help me with a snippet to filter between two dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Disclosure: I work on the Schematiq development team.)*

You can use a snippet like this:

`date => AND(date > *date1*, date < *date2*)`

The full call would be:

`=tbl.Filter(A1, "Date, "date => AND(date > *date1*, date < *date2*)")`

If those dates are in (say) cells A2 and A3 then you would write:

`=tbl.Filter(A1, "Date, "date => AND(date > " & A2 & ", date < " & A3 & ")")`

Alternatively, you could use txt.Format to create the snippet:

`=txt.Format("date => AND(date > {0}, date < {1})", A2:A3)`

Comment: Thanks Neil, that is great!